# How to synchronize sort markers between DataGrid and CollectionViewSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How do you achieve (preferably purely in XAML) that the sort marker in the column header of a WPF DataGrid is synchronized with the current sort order in a CollectionViewSource?

For example, I have the following example code which shows the attributes of all files in C:\, sorted by length:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridSortTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:cm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="items" Source="{Binding Files}">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <cm:SortDescription PropertyName="Length"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource items}}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code-behind in MainWindow.xaml.cs is:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\").Select(f => new FileInfo(f)).ToList();

        DataContext = this;
    }

    public IEnumerable<FileInfo> Files { get; private set; } 
}
```

When I start this program it looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

I.e. the files are sorted correctly, but the marker in the header is missing. With "marker", I mean this:

[image: Sort marker]

**NOTE**: I am looking for a **generic** solution. Just setting `DataGridColumn.SortDirection` is not a solution. I am looking for a way to instruct the DataGrid to automatically retrieve the sort order from the collection view.

Comment: does setting of property "Direction" helps? Cuz it is missing in your code. Can't verify now on my pc

Comment: @Artiom: No, setting `SortDescription.Direction` does not help.

Comment: interesting issue, may it's a bug. I've asked on msdn about that, may be these guys know what's the matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your generic solucion I have two proposals.

**First:**

You can create new DataGrid class and automaticly check SortDescriptions.

```
 class ExDataGrid : DataGrid
    {
        bool isFirstRow = true;

        protected override void OnLoadingRow(DataGridRowEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoadingRow(e);
            if (isFirstRow)
                SortDirectionHelper(this);
        }

        private void SortDirectionHelper(DataGrid dg)
        {
            var tmp = dg.Items.SortDescriptions;

            foreach (SortDescription sd in tmp)
            {
                var col = dg.Columns.Where(x => (((Binding)x.ClipboardContentBinding).Path.Path == sd.PropertyName)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (col != null)
                {
                    col.SortDirection = sd.Direction;
                }
            }

            isFirstRow = false;
        }
    }
```

Xaml file:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridSortTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:cm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:dg="clr-namespace:DataGridSortTest"
        >
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="items" Source="{Binding Files}" >
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <cm:SortDescription PropertyName="Length"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>      
        <dg:ExDataGrid x:Name="grid" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource items}}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Second:**

You can create EventHandler for Loaded event in every grid

```
 private void grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SortDirectionHelper(sender as DataGrid);
        }

        public void SortDirectionHelper(DataGrid dg)
        {
            var tmp = dg.Items.SortDescriptions;

            foreach (SortDescription sd in tmp)
            {
                var col = dg.Columns.Where(x => (((Binding)x.ClipboardContentBinding).Path.Path == sd.PropertyName)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (col != null)
                {
                    col.SortDirection = sd.Direction;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: In other words: there is no solution; you always must set `SortDirection` explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it is old question, but today I faced the same issue and have found a general solution for this. So, the idea is that SortDescriptions collection implements INotifyCollectionChanged implicitly and therefore we have ability to observe it and set DataGrid "sort markers" appropriately. I implemented this inside separate behavior:

```
public class DataGridSortDescriptionsSyncBehavior : Behavior<DataGrid>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(AssociatedObject.ItemsSource);
        var notifyCollection = view.SortDescriptions as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (notifyCollection != null)
            notifyCollection.CollectionChanged += SortDescriptions_CollectionChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();

        var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(AssociatedObject.ItemsSource);
        var notifyCollection = view.SortDescriptions as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (notifyCollection != null)
            notifyCollection.CollectionChanged -= SortDescriptions_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void SortDescriptions_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
        {
            // clear all columns sort directions
            foreach (var column in AssociatedObject.Columns)
                column.SortDirection = null;
        }

        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            // set columns sort directions
            foreach (SortDescription descr in e.NewItems)
                SetSortDirection(descr.PropertyName, descr.Direction);
        }

        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            // reset columns sort directions
            foreach (SortDescription descr in e.OldItems)
                SetSortDirection(descr.PropertyName, null);
        }
    }

    private void SetSortDirection(string sortMemberPath, ListSortDirection? direction)
    {
        var column = AssociatedObject.Columns.FirstOrDefault(c => c.SortMemberPath == sortMemberPath);
        if (column != null)
        {
            column.SortDirection = direction;
        }
    }
}
```

For those guys, who don't know about behaviors - you need to add reference to System.Windows.Interactivity assembly and apply behavior to the DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:DataGridSortDescriptionsSyncBehavior />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</DataGrid>
```

Now, when you modify your collection, "sort markers" automatically adjust. Also, please, note that this behavior works with default collection view only. If you are using your explicitly created collection view - simply send it to behavior (for example, via behavior's property) and use it instead of default collection view.

Comment: Could you expand on how to pass the explicitly-created view to the behaviour, please?

Comment: This behavior is not intended to work with explicit views. But if you want that, you can easily modify it. Just add Dependency Property of ICollectionView to the behavior. Inside the behavior - use DP instead of automatically created ones in OnAttached/OnDetaching. Outside the behavior - bind DP to your explicitly created view in view model.

Answer (score 0):

from msdn forum

> You need explicitly specify the SortDirection property on DataGrid
>   Columns to make the marker displayed in the column header, as the
>   marker feature is of DataGrid not binding source.

so perhaps u better to use @kmatyaszek solution